# HTTP endpoints was either down or not responding

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I made an action for Google Assistant using dialogue flow. When submitting the Action for production it's Getting denied.

[image]

The Webhook is on Firebase Function, the logs are empty. I re-submitted version 2 with changing the endpoint. Everything work when I test in the Simulator or my phone.

Do the Firebase function work only in particular region and not globally? If so there is no option to select the region

**UPDATE**

I did the deployment of Alpha as Nick suggested in the comments, It's failing in my all alpha testers too. Did I do something wrong in the configuration of the webhook or in the dialog flow code?

Here is my index.js
https://github.com/Aarth-Tandel/CountryName

Comment: HTTPS functions may be invoked from anywhere that is not blocked at the source.

Comment: I am not blocking it form my action. It's triggering when I test, however, AoG is not able to trigger it. Where is it getting blocked?

Comment: Are you able to see any logs in the Firebase functions console?

Comment: @Nick No, the logs are empty.

Comment: Can you use the alpha testers section to share with a friend and see if they'll be able to invoke it?

Comment: Ok, I will share the app and get back

Comment: @Nick you were correct the alpha testers faced the same problem.

Comment: Are you using `console.log` anywhere in your cloud function? You may want to log something simple to see if it's getting blocked at the Firebase function or at Dialogflow.

Comment: Yes,  I am logging in welcome intent itself. It is not hitting the web hook as the logs are empty.

Comment: Can you post some code samples of your webhook so that I and others can see what is happening?

Comment: I have uploaded index.js. Please have a look at it.